# Loading JSON data to the tableview not working

Tags: ios, json, uitableview, swift3

Below is my code.
Here print(currency) function is working.. That means, json data is retrieved. But doesn't shows in the tableview.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource { 
@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView! 
var TableData:Array< String > = Array < String >()

override func viewDidLoad()
{
   super.viewDidLoad()  
   get_data_from_url("http://api.fixer.io/latest")
}
```

Tableview part

```
public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return(TableData.count)
}

public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.default, reuseIdentifier: "cell")
    cell.textLabel?.text = TableData[indexPath.row] 
    return (cell)
}
```

JSON data retrieving

```
func get_data_from_url(_ link:String)
{
    let url = URL(string: "http://api.fixer.io/latest")

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { (data, response, error) in
        if error != nil
        {
            print ("ERROR")
        }
        else
        {
            if let content = data
            {
                do
                {
                    //Array
                    let myJson = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: content, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as AnyObject

                    if let rates = myJson["rates"] as? NSDictionary
                    {
                        if let currency = rates["NOK"] as? String
                        {
                            print(currency)
                            self.TableData.append(currency)
                            self.tableView.reloadData()
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch
                {

                }
            }
        }
    }
    task.resume()


}
```

The data is showing in the xcode with the print function. So it is clear that data is retrieving. But The problem is when loading the data to the tableview.
Please help me to load it.

Comment: Remove `public` from the tableView methods Also check your `tableView` `delegate` and `dataSourece` are properly connected with your viewController.

Comment: Again it doesn't works @NiravD

Comment: Reload the tableView on main thread like `DispatchQueue.main.async { self.tableView.reloadData() }`

Comment: Sorry. NOK was Double. Below answer helped. Thank you for your help @NiravD

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To fetch data .. (your NOK is not String.. its Double)

```
let myJson = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: content, options:[]) as [String:Any]

                if let rates = myJson["rates"] as? [String:Double],  
                   let currency = rates["NOK"] 
                {
                    print(currency)
                    self.tableData.append(String(currency))
                    DispatchQueue.main.async { 
                        self.tableView.reloadData() 
                    }
                }
```

---

```
// Declate array of String  
var tableData = [String]()

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return tableData.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = UITableViewCell(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: "cell")
    cell.textLabel?.text = tableData[indexPath.row] 
    return cell
}
```

Comment: Thank you @El Captain v2.0  .

Comment: @El  Captain v2.0 , for loading all the rates, what change is needed in the code. Iam confused with the string, double.. Plz help me

Comment: hows your table cell looks like?

Comment: Above I added only the rate of NOK. I need full data from that link

Comment: yes that I understand .. but you have all the rates in single cell?

Comment: I just added one rate.. That is in a single cell.. I need different rates in different cells

Comment: I meant all the rates separately in seperate cells. In above case I just added a single data ( ie, rate of NOK). I hope u checked the JSON link.

Comment: Ok.. Got It.. Thank you!

Comment: Can I contact you through email?? @El Captain v2.0   ??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134174/discussion-between-rash-and-ei-captain-v2-0).